# Is there any reason to use Azure Mobile Services instead of Web API?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have been using azure mobile services for my windows phone app and now want to create a website and use it but normally you use web API with the web apps.. Can someone tell me if it makes any sense to use azure mobile services instead and why?  I could not find anything on the web that addressed this topic

Comment: and why can't you use the C# mobile azure services with HTML ?  (the sample project for HTML only exists in the javascript one)

Answer (score 1):

It's true that anything you can do with Azure Mobile Services can be done with a "regular" Web API. But the former provides several capabilities that make it easier (see below) so it's your call whether you are interested to implement them yourself or leave it to the service:

- Quick access to tables: you tagged your question with `javascript` so I'm assuming you're using the node.js backend. It's fairly simple to store data on Azure by simply creating a table (in which you can set permissions) and using the client SDK
- Authentication: adding auth is usually a fairly complex task; with mobile services you can use social providers to quickly authenticate the users of your app
- Push notifications: mobile services is integrated with Notification Hubs, which makes sending push notifications to the client easier than if you had to talk to the push notification system directly
- Monitoring: for non-free mobile services, the site is monitored so that if by some reason it goes down the on-call engineers are notified to get it back up as soon as possible and identify why this is happening
- Integration with scheduled tasks: simple interface to execute tasks at a pre-determined interval

In short, if you're an experienced backend developer that knows how to implement those features, then you may be better off going with a "regular" Web API, otherwise Mobile Services can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

if you have written custom logic in your Mobile Services backend that you want to re-use and not want to rewrite for your new web app, then you may consider using Mobile Services for your web app.

the .NET backend for Mobile Services is actually Web API.